# Regex expression (C++) to take in ONLY a single character, no more

Tags: c++, regex, pattern-matching

I want to catch a string of either `M` or `A`.

this is the expression I'm using

```
(^[M]|[A]{1}$)
```

it confirms that `M` or `A` is inputted, but also for `MANY`, or `AMY`. where I only want one single character to pass through, no more no less.

Comment: like this: `^[MA]$` ?

Comment: Why use regex for this at all?

Comment: @MikeMB I have alot of character check for, maybe around 8 of them. I thought regex would be a good idea instead of 8 if statements.

Comment: Do you want to check each line in a string consisting of multiple lines or do you actually want to check whether a given string consists only of a ssinge M or A?

Comment: @Robolisk welcome! I put it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex simplified to `^M|A$` matches ( `M` at `^` start OR `A` at `$` end).
Just remove the alternation and put your characters into a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

```
^[MA]$
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qK0jI7/1). This matches one of the characters defined from start to end.